# Cast function type to differ if types of arguments are convertable

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I am writing a wrapper class for callable types (pointer to function, functors, etc). I want to implement something like std::function.

I define constructor from pointer to function:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
class function<Ret(Args...)>
{
public:
    function(Ret (func)(Args...))
    {
        m_fn_ptr = func;
    }
}
```

Now, let's assume that i want to use my class like this:

```
int int_function(int n)
{
    return n;
}

function<int(short)> wrapper(&int_function); // compile error
```

Despite that short are implicit convertable to int compiler cannot deduce template parameters and call appropriate constructor.

Then i tried this:

```
template <typename FRet, typename... FArgs>
function(FRet (func)(FArgs...))
{
    m_fn_ptr = static_cast<Ret (*f)(Args...)>(func);
}
```

But I got invalid static cast.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: If your `function` class can contain arbitrary callable objects (like `std::function`) this feature comes for free.

Comment: I suppose i can achieve that with type erasure idiom but is there another solution ? (because classic implementation of type erasure will lead me to dynamic memory allocation)

Comment: @EvgeniyMoiseenko Well, you can choose to only accept function pointers and save those in a `void*`.

Comment: The very reason to have a `function` class if to type erase. If you need a function pointer use a function pointer. Also no, dynamic allocation is not always necessary. `std::function` uses a member buffer for small objects.

Comment: Are you up to having two pointers worth of state, instead of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `super_func` is a function object with no state that can convert to any compatible call signature.

```
template<class T>using type=T;

template<class Sig, Sig* func>
struct super_func;
template<class R, class...Args, R(*func)(Args...)>
struct super_func<R(Args...), func> {
  using Sig = R(Args...);
  using pSig = Sig*;
  template<class R2, class...Args2, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_convertible<
      std::result_of_t<pSig(Args2...)>,
      R2
    >{}
    && !std::is_same<R2, void>{},
  bool
  > =true>
  constexpr operator type<R2(Args2...)>*() const {
    return [](Args2...args)->R2{
      return func(std::forward<Args2>(args)...);
    };
  }
  template<class...Args2, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<
      std::result_of_t<pSig(Args2...)>,
      R
    >{},
  bool
  > =true>
  constexpr operator type<void(Args2...)>*() const {
    return [](Args2...args)->void{
      func(std::forward<Args2>(args)...);
    };
  }
  constexpr operator pSig() const {
    return func;
  }
  constexpr R operator()(Args...args)const{
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27790a2a2b14d13d).  A `super_func` is stateless.  To use it on a function foo, do:

```
super_func< decltype(foo), &foo > super_foo;
```

and you get a callable stateless empty object which behaves a lot like `foo` does, except you can assign it to a pointer to any compatible function pointer and it generates it "on the fly" at compile time.

A `super_foo` can be fed to your function object.

Doing this on the fly doesn't work without the exterior help, as we need the `foo` to be a truly static bit of information.  By the time it becomes a variable, it is too late to do this statelessly, so we cannot use the lambda trick (without an extra pvoid) to generate a function pointer for the exact signature we want.

You could do a macro:

```
#define SUPER(X) super_func< decltype(X), &X >{}
```

and then create your `function` object with `function<double()> f(SUPER(foo));`

---

Another approach is to store an extra pointer's worth of state, and create "the fastest possible delegate" style type erasure.  (that term can be googled for one of many implementations, each faster than the last).

Comment: Introduced usage of enable_if seems to have a mistake. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes

Comment: @gleb only in certain (annoyingly common) cases.  But anyhow, I patched code in answer with technique that avoids the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix that ?

Use the correct types when creating `wrapper`.

Instead of using

```
function<int(short)> wrapper(&int_function);
```

use

```
function<int(int)> wrapper(&int_function);
```

Remember that class templates instantiated with `int` and `short` are very different types and are not convertible to each other.

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {};

Foo<int> a;
Foo<short> b = a; // Not OK.

Foo<short> c;
Foo<int> d = c; // Not OK.
```

Comment: This basically ignores the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `function` constructor expects a pointer to a function that takes a `short`, not an `int`. The fix is to provide it such a function. The easiest way to do that is to use a lambda with an empty capture-list, that is implicitly convertible to a function pointer:

```
function<int(short)> wrapper( [](short s) { return int_function(s); } );
```